# Electron+Vue: Custom Titlebar -> Getting the correct maximized/restored window state from within component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vue-component

I'm developing a frameless application with a custom titlebar (Electron + Vue + Vuex, using electron-vue boilerplate).
So far, I've managed to toggle the maximize/restore buttons **when they are clicked**.

The problem is when the windows state is controled by other events, like double clicking the title bar to maximize or the taskbar icon (Windows) to minimize/restore.

Is there a way to add some sort of event listener to react to windows changes from inside the component (.vue), in order to show the correct maximize/restore button?

Comment: I think `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain` may be what you're looking for

Comment: I know how to emit from ipcMain, but don't know how to listen from a single file component in Vue. Where should I put the `ipcRenderer.on` ? In methods, in a computed value,...? Thanks for the help

Comment: It highly depends on what the ipcRender.on is for, however, I would place it in a mutation and update a specific state based on the response

Comment: At first, I'd like even to be able to do something as simple as a "ping-pong" test. The problem is my ipcRender isn't listening to the "pong".
(I know ipcMain is working because I can close the app from the vue component button)

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a while, so far this is how I managed to do it:

in electron-main.js

```
    mainWindow.on("move", () => {
        //_ console.log("electron move");
        mainWindow.webContents.send("winState", "normal");
    });
    mainWindow.on("minimize", () => {
        //_ console.log("electron minimize");
        mainWindow.webContents.send("winState", "minimized");
    });
    mainWindow.on("maximize", () => {
        //_ console.log("electron maximize");
        mainWindow.webContents.send("winState", "maximized");
    });
    mainWindow.on("unmaximize", () => {
        //_ console.log("electron unmaximize");
        mainWindow.webContents.send("winState", "normal");
    });
    mainWindow.on("restore", () => {
        //_ console.log("electron restore");
        mainWindow.webContents.send("winState", "normal");
    });
```

in electron-preload.js

```
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from "electron";
import { BrowserWindow } from "@electron/remote";

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("csxAPI", {
    envMode: process.env.MODE,
    minimize() {
        BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().minimize();
    },
    maximize() {
        BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().maximize();
    },
    restore() {
        BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().unmaximize();
    },
    close() {
        BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().close();
        BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().destroy();
    },
});

const validChannels = ["winState"];
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipc", {
    send: (channel, data) => {
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
        }
    },
    on: (channel, func) => {
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            // Strip event as it includes `sender` and is a security risk
            //_ ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            ipcRenderer.on(channel, (...args) => func(...args));
        }
    },
});
```

in TitleBar.vue

```
//...
data: function () {
        return {
            status: "normal",
        };
    },

//...
mounted() {
        window.ipc.on("winState", (event, msg) => {
            this.status = msg;
        });

//...
methods: {
        winMinimize() {
            if (window.csxAPI.envMode === "electron") {
                window.csxAPI.minimize();
            }
        },
        winMaximize() {
            if (window.csxAPI.envMode === "electron") {
                window.csxAPI.maximize();
            }
        },
        winRestore() {
            if (window.csxAPI.envMode === "electron") {
                window.csxAPI.restore();
            }
        },
        winClose() {
            if (window.csxAPI.envMode === "electron") {
                window.csxAPI.close();
            }
        },
    },
```

Don't know if it's optimized or even if it's the right way to do it, but it worked for me.

Thanks to those who tried to help